# UIViewController is dismissing automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a problem with a ViewController.

In hierarchy i have 3 ViewController:

- Login
- Grid
- Profile

From Login to Grid, there is no problem. But when i'm try to go from Grid to Profiel, Grid is dismissed, i'm using:

```
ProfileViewController *perfil = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:perfil animated:YES completion:nil];
```

from a Table, but i try from a button action too.

I create other viewcontroller (testviewcontroller) and try to present it and the same problem.

The view is presented, when i set animated to "YES" the view is presented, but just when it finish the parent is dismissed.

To clarify:

From grid controller no matter what i do, when profile (or test) controller is presented, grid is dismissed automatically.

I never see something like that.

Can anyone help me?

New info:

I create a new controller and instead to go from login to grid, i'm tried to go from login to the new controller, and the same problem happen.

New info (more weird):

I have this 2 calls to present a controller:

```
- (IBAction)ingresar:(id)sender
{
    aViewController *grilla = [[aViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    grilla.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:grilla animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)registro:(id)sender
{
    RegistroViewController *registro = [[RegistroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    registro.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:registro animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The first have the issue of magically dissapear, the second dont...

Comment: Post your -viewDidLoad method of the ProfileViewController.

Comment: is just - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

Comment: Hmm, are you calling -dismissViewController...animated.. anywhere?

Comment: Nop, i triple check manually and search in workspace twice.

Comment: How do you know Grid is dismissed? Are you using a stroyboard at all, or xib files?

Comment: I'm using xib files. I assume is dismissed because it disappear and "login" re-appear

Comment: What do you mean "login reappear"? When you present perfil, don't you see perfil? When does login reappear?

Comment: If animates is NO, i cant see it, if YES i can see it. But just when Profile is presented, Profile and Grid dissapear. Login "re-appear" cause is parent of Grid, so when Grid and Profile dissapear, Login is showed.

Comment: So, you present `grid` from `login`, then present `perfil` from `grid`, and at the time when perfil animation ends, both perfil and grid controllers are magically dismissed and you end up at `login`, right?

Comment: And i create other controller (to test) and now the problem is from Login to test. Y put a break on Login viewdidappear and is called every time the other controllers are dismissed.

Comment: Looks like `grid` is prematurely released. Put breakpoint at grid's dealloc and release (or NSLog them at first), and bring us stack trace from there. (Unless you use ARC, in which I don't know how to catch such errors)

Comment: That makes no sense. I would have to see your project to understand what's going on. When you present a view controller, it has a strong pointer to the controller that presented it, so nothing should be being deallocated.

Comment: rdelmar i know that make no sense, that is why i'm here :)

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so we can't diagnose the problem. If you can send me the project or post it somewhere (or a test project that shows the same behavior), I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Naive question: are you sure you `retain`ed `grid` in `login` (or have strong reference to it, if you're in ARC)?

Comment: Hint: we do not see notifications, if you write our nicknames without @

Comment: @rdelmar I cant send this project :/ I can not do the same thing happening in a test (im' gonna insist with that)

Comment: @Artur (thanks for the @ info) i'm gonna say no, how can i be sure of that?

Comment: If you [[alloc] init] and store it somewhere, it is retained (unless you release it by the way). Under ARC you have to assign it to strong property. Are you using ARC?

Comment: @Artur, he shouldn't need to have a strong reference. The window has a strong pointer to the root view controller (which is presumably the login controller), and each controller that presents has a strong pointer to the one it presented, and that presented one also has a strong pointer to the one that presented it.

Comment: @rdelmar Okay, but what we see here? That bad thing happens when animation ends. Animation ends -> previous view is released (or previous view controller is released). And when it is released, cascaded releases kill both view controllers. I don't insist on anything, but maybe that is the place where he should start to dig. Why not give it a small try?

Comment: Do you have other controllers, or are these 3 all you have? When going from login to Grid, are you using the same code you showed?

Comment: @Artur, I'm not saying that you shouldn't try, I'm just stating the facts. Maybe adding strong references will fix the problem (who knows?), but if it does, it still doesn't explain the current behavior, because this shouldn't happen even without any explicit strong references (assuming he's using ARC, if not I'm not sure).

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in the console when you see this behavior? You might try cleaning the project, shutting down Xcode, and restarting just make sure something didn't get screwed up along the way.

Comment: @rdelmar Technically, there is no proof that `presentViewController...` retains anything, because docs say it just sets `presentedViewController` and `presentingViewController` properties of both (and starts animation), but they declared `readonly` (is `strong` implied?). I think it is overestimation of framework and/or ARC capabilities. General rule always was: if you need it -- retain it. Or use strong property. Or you'll lose it some day.

Comment: @Artur, Strong is the default, so making your own strong pointer is redundant.  If you look at Apple's example code in the docs on presenting view controllers from other view controllers, you will see that they use only local variables not properties when creating and presenting a modal view controller. This not only works fine, but is normally the way you want to do it so the presented controller will be deallocated after it's dismissed (without having to set a strong pointer to nil).

Comment: @Artur , rdelmar thanks to both for your time, i cant test it right now , but as soon as I try this I'll let you know. I not. i'm not using arc. Thanks again guys.

Comment: I've tested what I think you're doing, both with and without ARC, and I can't duplicate your problem. Everything works fine for me.

Comment: @Artur i tried forcing the "retain" but nothing, i will create another project and copy everything. Thank to everyone

Comment: original question edited with more "info"

Comment: Well, i create a new project and transfer everything to this new project. The problem continue...

Comment: It seems that the problem is with the "news" controller, i call an old controller from the same place and it works. But when i create a new controller and try to call it, the problem occurs

Comment: @rdelmar yes, i create a complete new project, with another controller, and the problem persist... next step, re-install xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

i dont know why, but after trying almost everything (including re-installing Xcode) the problem was that in a controller, i was presenting other controller inside

```
viewDidAppear
```

i have used this many times before and never happened this, i only can believe that is karma saying "that was a bad practice, b**ch"

Comment: Did this not give you warnings like "Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"?